# command-line zip not working

Tags: wordpress, server, linux

I have a Wordpress site on a Debian/Linux dedicated server, with a Backupbuddy plugin for making automatic backups.

The plugin, however, gives an error 'Your server does not support command line ZIP'.

My knowledge of Linux commands is very limited, but I managed installing zip with the command `sudo apt-get install zip`

However, I still get the same error message. Plugin documentation mentions the problem could also be caused by disabled exec() or safe_mode - but exec isn't disabled, and safe_mode is off.

Any ideas what might be causing this, or how to fix it? The only thing I could think of, is it might be caused by wrong permissions?

Comment: try: "yum install zip" and if it still doesn't work - switch to user-root and try again

Comment: thanks for the comment - however, that's not the problem, `yum` doesn't work, and the command I used results in `zip already installed`...

Answer (score 1):

- Update BackupBuddy to latest version as there as been some fixes on this issue.
- Backupbuddy says to do [sudo apt-get install zip **unzip**](http://ithemes.com/codex/page/BackupBuddy%3a_Frequent_Support_Issues#Compatibility_Mode) (in your question you didn't mention that you had unzip install thought you might).
- Even though you have edited php.ini make sure these rules are being read create a info.php with the following code  and point browser to this file.
- Ensure the zip and unzip is in the [PATH environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)